# Creating permanent PYTHONPATH not working

Tags: php, python, bash, pythonpath, .profile

I have been trying to set up a permanent PYTHONPATH in my /.bash_profile, but it doesn't seem to be working. I can get it to work for one session, then it will be blank the next time I try. Or, as happened today, it remains blank. If I had to guess, I would say it is because I also have a path set in my /.profile, but I am getting very confused by the whole situation and would appreciate some assistance.

Contents of my /.profile (my PHP path setup)

```
export     PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/:/usr/share/php/pear/bin/:$PATH
```

Contents of my /.bash_profile

```
PYTHONPATH=...~/src:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

For the PYTHONPATH path, I have left out some of the identifying information of my computer with the ...~/ at the start, but it is all in the file.

I have set up the symlink for Python and that appears to be working correctly.

I would really appreciate your insights!

Comment: PATH and PYTHONPATH are 2 different variables.  You want to include $PYTHONPATH (keep the existing path and extend it), as is the case in the second PATH statement posted.  Something like

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python/site-python:/usr/lib64/python/:  And note the colon separator.  Look in bash.profile and it should source bashrc, so putting it in bashrc is enough if you are running from a terminal.  Check for yourself, but I think bashrc is for the terminal and bash.profile for everything else.

Comment: It turned out that this was a problem with the fact that I was using zsh instead of bash. As a result, the bash_profile was not running. I put it in zprofile instead and now it's working. Just in case anyone else runs into this issue!